# $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\frac{a_n}{n!}\in\mathbb{Q}\Longleftrightarrow\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon a_n=n-1\forall n\ge N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Given integers $a_1,a_2,...$ such that $1\le a_n\le n-1$ , $n=2,3,...$
>   Show that the sum of the series $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\frac{a_n}{n!}$ is rational if and only if there exists integer $N$ such that $a_n=n-1$ for all $n\ge N$.

**My attempt**
**If part:** $a_n=n-1$ $\forall n\ge N$
$\Rightarrow\frac{a_n}{n!}=\frac{n-1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}$ $\forall n\ge N$
$\Rightarrow\underset{k=N}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\frac{a_k}{k!}=\frac{1}{(N-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}$
$\Rightarrow\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\frac{a_n}{n!}=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\underset{n=N}{\overset{n}{\sum}}\frac{a_n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(N-1)!}\in\mathbb{Q}$

> I need help with the only if part.

Comment: Wow. That's the most interesting question I see tonight. May I ask the source of the problem?

Comment: sorry @Whatsup, it seems that by "Cantor's number system" is hard to find some source, try with "factorial number system". This was a numerical system studied by Cantor, it is mentioned (and there is an equivalent exercise to the one of @zaira) in the textbook _Analysis I_ of Amann & Escher

Comment: @Masacroso Ah, thanks for that! Now it's easy to find the wiki page (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}=\frac{b}{c}.$$

Multiply both sides by $c!$ to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^cc!\frac{a_n}{n!}+\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{a_n}{n!}=b(c-1)!.$$

Now, note that the first term on the left and the term on the right are both integers. In addition, since

$$\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{a_n}{n!}>0,$$

we have

$$\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{a_n}{n!}\in\mathbb{N}$$

(note here that $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$). Now, if not all $a_n=n-1$, we have that

$$\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{a_n}{n!}<\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{n-1}{n!}$$

(note the strictly less than condition). However, this is

$$\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{a_n}{n!}<\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{n-1}{n!}=1.$$

Thus, $\sum_{n=c+1}^\infty c!\frac{a_n}{n!}$ is an integer between $0$ and $1$, an impossibility. We conclude

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}\not\in\mathbb{Q}.$$

Comment: That's what people call "Fourier's proof". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational#Fourier's_proof

Comment: so instead of proving $A\Rightarrow B$, we prove $B^c\Rightarrow A^c$